# Aggregation Query in Discover not returning expected result (Kibana / Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I have set up a Kibana / Elasticsearch instance to analyze some Data that i'm scraping.
I am analyzing news Articles from different websites, i want to use a query / Filter that only shows me Articles once by using a cardinality aggregation on the Field "article_id".

To do so i have set up a Lens Visualization, added the Visualization to a Dashboard and got the Request from Visualization via the "Inspect" option. Then i tried to use the Request as a Filter in the Discover Tab ("Edit as Query DSL"). The only thing that seems to be affected by the query is the time. When i run the Query in the "Dev Tools" Section it does just fine.

My Request looks like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "696b506b-2d7f-4bfc-9fab-704ca6e95d5c": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "article_title.keyword",
        "order": {
          "acbaafc6-829d-4c65-9b6b-cbca538c938e": "desc"
        },
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "acbaafc6-829d-4c65-9b6b-cbca538c938e": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "article_id.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "run_date",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "scrape_date",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "runtime_mappings": {},
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "run_date": {
              "gte": "2021-04-02T23:49:43.440Z",
              "lte": "2021-04-17T23:49:43.440Z",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as this has been driving me insane the last few hours...